# jackson deserialization anysetter NPE

Tags: jackson

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Payer{
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

When I use `objectmepper.readValue(json_string, Payer.class)` with following json string:

```
{
   "name": "fakeName",
   "state": "verifird"
}
```

I get NPE. Since I have `@JsonAnySetter`, the `state` string should be put into `additionalProperties`, I'd like to know why do I get NPE here?

Answer (score 0):

Include getter and setter for `name` in `Payer` class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class Payer{
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Parse the Json:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json_string = "{\n" +
        "   \"name\": \"fakeName\",\n" +
        "   \"state\": \"verifird\"\n" +
        "}";
    Payer readValue = mapper.readValue(json_string , Payer.class);
    System.out.println(readValue.getName());
    System.out.println(readValue.getAdditionalProperties());
  }
```

Output:

```
fakeName
{state=verifird}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have already `@Data` annotation of lombok, it has getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late but I have a similar issue and discovered the problem was in the Lombok builder. I believe the same might be issued by the constructor with `additionalProperties` parameter without `@JsonIgnore`, so you should check if this annotation is added to the generated constructor parameter. (it could be added using `lombok.config`)

I solve the problem by excluding the field from the builder according to [How to exclude property from Lombok builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30717640/11022837).