# I'm not able to get @RequiredArgsConstructor work when combined with @Builder

Tags: java, constructor, builder, lombok

I've tried to use Lombok's @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation with the @Builder annotation.
When I do the following:

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Test
{
   private final String email;
   private final String name;
   private String password;
}
```

Everything works fine and as expected, but when I add the @Builder annotation:

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Test
{
   private final String email;
   private final String name;
   private String password;
}
```

I get the following error during the build:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project example: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/[...]/Test.java:[9,1] constructor Test in class [...]Test cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR]   found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Is this a Lombok bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Lombok in version 1.18.4.

EDIT:
Ok, thank you for your answers.
Now it gets a little bit more complex.
I want to build an OkHttpClient inside the generated constructor.

```java
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Builder
public class Test
{
   private final String email;
   private final String name;
   private String password;

   @Builder.Default
   private final long timeout = 60000L;

   private OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
}
```

When I'm doing so i get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project example: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/[...]/Test.java:[25,79] variable timeout might not have been initialized
```

Is there any possibility to do so without writing the code of the constructor on my own?
This is also the reason why I tried to avoid using the @AllArgsConstructor annotation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `@AllArgsConstructor` to make it available for the builder.

If you don't specify any constructor, `@Builder` will create one, however if there is at least one constructor, it won't.

Try this:

```
import lombok.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Builder
public class Test
{
   private final String email;
   private final String name;
   private String password;
}
```

`@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)` is what the `@Builder` would have generated if there were no constructor.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I've edited my question so you can see what I really wanted to do, I think the @AllArgsConstructor brings some problems in this use-case?!

Comment: @Carsten It's a different question, please create a new question and give me its link in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@RequiredArgsConstructor` with an `@AllArgsConstructor`. The issue arose because `@Builder` can't construct your `Test` class as it only has this constructor

```
public Test(String email, String name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
}
```

But `@Builder` wants to do:

```
public Test build() {
    return new Test(email, name, password);
}
```

You can discover the root of these issues easily with the delombok tool.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible to generate a constructor and builder which ignores the password String?

Comment: To learn how to customize your builder you can follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717640/how-to-exclude-property-from-lombok-builder

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the `okHttpClient` field final, and, if you wish lazy.

```java
   @Getter(lazy=true)
   private final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
```

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.