# Different constructors (LOMBOK)

Tags: java, constructor, annotations, lombok

I have a class that looks like this:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StatusUpdate {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NonNull
    private String text;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NonNull
    private Date added; 
}
```

And I want to create these two constructors using Lombok:

```
public StatusUpdate(String text) {
     this.text = text;
}

public StatusUpdate(String text, Date added) {
     this.text = text;
     this.added = added;
}
```

I tried using all three annotations:
*@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor*

But I couldn't do that with these, I only have one constructor that has two parameters, so I need one more constructor with one parameter only. I read this topic: [@SomeArgsConstructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761242/java-lombok-omitting-one-field-in-allargsconstructor) and this is what I need but since this does not exists I guess I should create manually one arg constructor that I need and other constructors I'll handle with Lombok, or is there any better / more elegant way to do it using Lombok only?

Thanks!

Comment: Someone in the post you linked suggested to use the Lombok `@Builder`. Otherwise I doubt there is any preferred way to go about it.

Comment: You can add them manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you should just add them yourself. Years ago there was [already a discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/project-lombok/c/USvN3CCy_BY) to add the `@SomeArgsConstructor` annotation, but since the Lombok team never did add that annotation, I think it is unlikely they will ever do it.

Or, as stated in the comments, use the builder pattern with the [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) annotation. Then you could write something like: `StatusUpdate.builder().text("text").date(new Date()).build();`.

---

*Btw, if you do annotate all your fields with `@Getter`, `@Setter` and use the `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` on class level, I think the [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation could be a good fit for this class.*

Answer (score 0):

use `@Builder` annotation with your entity class and build your object manually.

```
 User user = User.builder()
                    .username(signupDto.getUsername())
                    .email(signupDto.getEmail())
                    .password(encoder.encode(signupDto.getPassword()))
                    .roles(roles)
                    .build();
```