# Is there a way to use Lombok's @builder with a limited set of attributes in the constructor?

Tags: java, lombok

I'm working on a project which uses the Builder pattern. But this team uses Builder constructor arguments for the "required" attributes, and the builder "setters" for the optional stuff.

Here is an example where `name` is required and `age` is optional.

```java
Person person = Person.Builder("Bob Belcher").age(23).build();
```

When I apply `@Builder`, is there anyway I can instruct Lombok to add specified attributes in the builder's constructor?

Comment: Short answer: no. You can refactor the code to use no-args builders relatively easily (if you are using intellij).

Comment: I would maybe do that if this project didn't have other people who have a preference already established. Plus, I see why they like it, it's a nice way to enforce required attributes at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an overloaded static method `builder` taking the required arguments and returning the builder object. Thus lombok won't be generating a `builder` method since we have already defined it.

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Person {
    // fields....
    public static PersonBuilder builder(String name) {
        return new PersonBuilder().name(name);
    }       

}
```

The `private` access level could enforce that the object be created using only the `of` method.

For the requirement of "*builder setters for the optional stuff*", such that you cannot invoke `name()` on the builder object, you may try to override the builder methods for the required arguments to make it `private`. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67401875/7804477). (Also related [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68037001/7804477))

```java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Person {
    // fields....
    public static PersonBuilder builder(String name) {
        return new PersonBuilder().name(name);
    }       

    public static class PersonBuilder  {
        private PersonBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

// invoke as 
Person.builder("my name").age(23).build();
```

Comment: You can simply reuse the `builder()` method and give it parameters. Lombok will detect that there is already a method named `builder` and won't create another (overloaded) one, regardless of its parameters. In this way, there is no need to make the regular method private.