# Lombok: Generate 2 constructors with specified fields

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok, spring-annotations

So I want to generate two constructors using the

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Foo {
    @NonNull
    private String a;
     @NonNull
    private double b;
    private int c;
}
```

My class would be generating a constructer with a & b. But what If I also want to generate a second contructor with b & c? Is there any solution using annnotations?

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761242/java-lombok-omitting-one-field-in-allargsconstructor you can use builder(s) instead constructor(s)

Comment: So sadly the only way is Builder and I can't do it through annotation I see :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Lombok documentation, you can't do this. in another language you can not have different constructors with combinations of some fields. a better solution is to use @Builder